# Existence of a function satisfying certain property

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist a holomorphic function $f$ in a disc of radius 2 centered 
at the origin satisfying the property 
$f(\frac{1}{n}) = e^{-n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$? How would you prove this?

Comment: Looks like a homework.

Comment: I don't think there's a singularity at infinity here.